# SwiftのOptional Bindingでネストが深くなってしまう

Tags: swift

Optional String型のimageURLStringに画像のURLが格納されており、その画像をimageViewで表示したいと考えています。

以下のコードで動作はしますが、ネストが深くなりすぎてしまいます。
よりシンプルな書き方があれば、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

```
if let imageURLString = imageURLString {
    if let urlString = imageURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.imageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harawo様の回答にあるように、Swift1.2からは複数のOptional Bindingを1行で書けるようになります。

```
if let imageURLString = imageURLString, urlString = imageURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), url = NSURL(string: urlString), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil), image = UIImage(data: data) {
    self.imageView.image = image
}
```

回答者様ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Swift 1.2より、書式が追加になって、より短い記述ができるようになるそうです。

```
if let imageURLString = imageURLString, let urlString = imageURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), let url = NSURL(string: urlString), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
    self.imageView.image = image
}
```

このように、カンマで区切って記述ができるそうです。
詳しくは、「Swift 1.2」などをキーワードにして、ネット検索してください。
しばらくのがまん、といったところでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
たしかにSwift1.2では複数のOptional Bindingを1行で書けるようですね。
情報ありがとうございます！

ちなみに、カンマで区切った後のletは不要なようです。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じで多少浅くできました。
※申し訳ありません、エラーが出ないところまでしか確認していないです。

```
if let imageURLString = imageURLString?.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: imageURLString) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            view.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? nil
        }
    }
}
```

----- 追記 -----
少々ネタ的で恐縮ですが

```
func test() {
    let imageURLString: String? = "画像のパス"        
    if let data = imageURLString?.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.urlFromString()?.dataFromURL() {
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data) ?? nil
    }
}

extension String {

    func urlFromString() -> NSURL? {
        return NSURL(string: self)
    }
}

extension NSURL {

    func dataFromURL() -> NSData? {
        return NSData(contentsOfURL: self)
    }
}
```

これで画像表示はできました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
確かに、Optionalを返すメソッドを追加することによって、1行で書けるようになりますね！
@Harawo様の回答にあるように、Swift1.2からは複数のOptional Bindingを1行で書けるようになるので、それまでは我慢しようとおもいますw